# python3 interpreter gives different results than script for scipy.misc.imread

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to read image data into Python as a matrix.

To this extent, I am trying to use `scipy.misc.imread('image.jpg').astype(np.float)`.

When I execute the proper sequence of steps from a `python3` interpreter, everything works swimmingly, and I get a matrix as expected.

When I invoke the command from a script (`python3 foo.py`...), however, I get an error complaining that the argument to convert via `float` cannot be of type `JpegImageFile`.  I've ensured that I've `pip install -U pillow` to ensure that PIL is available.

What gives?  How could this be possible?  I've verified over and over that the same lines of code are executed in each case, the only difference seems to be that the invocation inside of a script happens inside of a defined function, but even if I `pdb.set_trace()` from elsewhere in the script the same results happen.

What could be causing fluctuation in results from the interpreter to the script?

**EDIT**: OK, to be precise, I am running the `neural_style.py` script from here: https://github.com/anishathalye/neural-style . `scipy`, `numpy`, `tensorflow`, and `pillow` must be installed.  I am using `python3`.  Any parameters for `--content`, `--styles`, and `--output` should work to dupe the bug.

Full error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "neural_style.py", line 150, in <module>
    main()
  File "neural_style.py", line 84, in main
    content_image = imread(options.content)
  File "neural_style.py", line 141, in imread
    return scipy.misc.imread(path).astype(np.float)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'JpegImageFile'
```

But, a small simple script such as the following actually works:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.misc
print(scipy.misc.imread('content').astype(np.float))
```

Comment: Your question lacks a [mcve] and doesn't even have a full error traceback, so it's going to be hard to track down the problem.

Comment: Added more information.

Comment: Still not a reproducible, self-contained example.  I downloaded the 549MB (!) support file needed to run `neural_style.py`, ran it in both python 2.7 and 3.4, and it worked just fine.  Either give a specific MCVE, or put add some prints to `neural_style.py` to find out what it thinks all the components of `scipy.misc.imread(path).astype(np.float)` are at the time, or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution to this.  The `neural_style.py` script seems to be getting a different version of `scipy` module (or submodule) due to a side effect of importing `stylize.py` and, in turn, `vgg.py`.  Adding this line:

```
import scipy.misc
```

To the very top of `stylize.py` (in front of `import vgg`) fixes it.

I'm really not sure why, though.